# Converting remaining time to actual date and time

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have this time format.

**For example**: `04d 03h 15m`,

when obviously is the time left for something to end or expire. How can I convert that to an actual date and time from now using PHP. As in this example, Say today is `19/1/2017 5:45am`, `4 days` from now is going to be `23rd Jan 2017, 3:15 am`.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by using `Date()` and `time()` with `strtotime()` and Try this code

```
$currenttime = time();
echo date('d/m/y  H:i A', $currenttime);
$timeAfterAdding = strtotime("+4 days +3 hours +15 minutes", $currenttime);
$expireTime = date('d/m/y  H:i A', $timeAfterAdding);

echo $expireTime;
```

**output:**

current time => 19/01/17  05:12 AM 
expire time  => 23/01/17  09:27 AM